# Have Brakeman and/or Jenkins email me if security vulnerabilities are found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, brakeman

I have the brakeman rake task set to run automatically through Jenkins, however since I have already addressed the initial security vulnerabilities that it found, Brakeman now runs clean 99% of the time.  I don't want to have to open the report every time to see that there are no issues.  I want it (Jenkins, Brakeman, or something custom) to notify me via email (or some other way) if it finds a new vulnerability.

Can anyone think of an approach for doing this?

Comment: hmm. I can think of creating a CRON job or even (Sidekiq or any other BG worker) that runs brakeman every night, and from that if brakeman returns non-zero, then it means something went wrong. I might also use [Exception Notification gem](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification) to send me the email with the contents of the security vulnerability

Answer (score 3):

Here are two options:

- Run Brakeman with `-z` or `rake brakeman:check` (you may have to replace the current Rake task with `brakeman --rake` to add this option) which will return a non-zero exit code if any warnings are found. This should fail your build. In Jenkins, add "E-mail Notification" as a "Post-build Action" to send you an email.
- Use the [Brakeman Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Brakeman+Plugin). You will need to change how Brakeman is run [as documented here](http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/jenkins/setup/). Then use the "Advanced..." options for the plugin to set thresholds to mark the build as unstable or fail the build. Once that is set up, add "E-mail Notification" as a "Post-build Action" to send you an email.

*[Running Brakeman with Rake is not really recommended since it unnecessarily loads your entire application.]*

Comment: Thanks Justin.  For some reason brakeman --rake doesn't generate the brakeman:check task, but I looked at the source and found that I can use result.filtered_warnings.empty? to determine if there were any vulnerabilities found, and if so send an email.

Comment: Odd, works for me: $ brakeman --rake
Task created in lib/tasks/brakeman.rake
Usage: rake brakeman:run[output_file]
$ rake -T -f lib/tasks/brakeman.rake 
rake brakeman:check              # Check your code with Brakeman
rake brakeman:run[output_files]  # Run Brakeman

Comment: It won't overwrite your existing file, though.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up enhancing the brakeman:run task to send emails if it finds any issues:

```
namespace :brakeman do

desc "Run Brakeman"
task :run, :emails do |t, args|
  require 'brakeman'

  file = ["tmp/brakeman_reports/brakeman_on_#{Date.today.to_s}.html"]

  result = Brakeman.run :app_path => ".", :output_files => file, :print_report => true

  unless result.filtered_warnings.empty?
    BrakemanReportMailer.notify(args[:emails]).deliver
  end
```

end
end